# This script works in firefox yet can't make it work with IE 7, 8, 9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

I have a script that I run which prints document body in a pop up. It works and firefox is jolly happy, but it does not work in IE.

In IE I used to not get even the popup because I had a second parameter in my window.open function but after removing that I get the pop up yet it is blank.

What could be possibly make this work with IE?

```
     var popUp= window.open('', '', "height=700,width=700,scrollbars=yes");
     $('#myFormId').clone().appendTo(popUp.document.body);
```

Any help?

Thanks

IE #%#SFSFDS !!!

Comment: validate your javascript code http://www.jshint.com

Comment: It's really IE in this case. IE refuses to append elements from a document to another, i.e. when you do `elem.appendTo(popUp)`, `elem` should be in the same document with `popUp`. Unfortenately it seems that there's no workaround for this.

Comment: I guess I could give option to the element itself, I guess this should work for now: `$(#'myFormId').print();`

Comment: This work in IE, `popUp.document.write($('#myFormId').html());` (tested on IE10) with this you will not have events and data binds to elements.

Comment: jcubic this works, please add it to answer if you wish.

Comment: Actually it does not include if the form contains input info:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my work around to make this work to print the page.

unwrap from tabs, print and hide it again.

```
$('.ui-tabs-panel').show();
window.print();
$('.ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden=true]').hide();
```

Hope this helps someone who tries to accomplish something similar.

Thanks